# How to integrate httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8096" into app.config [Webservices]

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a webservice which waits for a xml to arrive. Today we noticed, that the XML sometimes seems to be too large. Now I wanted to add `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10096"
        useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
        executionTimeout="120"/>` to my app.config. Unfortunately it seems to have no effect... Here is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10096"
        useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
        executionTimeout="120"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <client />
    <standardEndpoints />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataSupport" name="iib.wohnpreis.wohnpreisserver">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="URLToWebservice" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataSupport">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="wohnpreis/mex" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions what went wrong?
Thank you for trying to help me!

Steffi

Comment: What does "seems to be too large" mean? What error do you get? How are you hosting?

Comment: Too large means the file size is over 8kb - if we cut off the xml to match a smaller file size the service gets the xml. If not, nothing gets through to the service. A real error isn't showing up. Only this behaviour.
The webservice lies on a pc in our company. We didn't have any problems with that until now.

Comment: Seems like it isn't a problem of our webservice... We have a foreign company which provides a client written in PHP. This client is sending the XML. If the XML is < 8kb everything is fine. > 8kb is like nothing is send to the webservice. Could it be that they have misconfigured there script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the problem. The server told the client that the maxStringContentLength was limited to 8096 - which is not true because we defined it with

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Unfortunately this only works if we delete the `name="basicHttpBinding"` so it looks like

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Don't know how the name is interfering with the configuration - but without the name it works fine...